# Cloudant query indexing not working Android

Tags: cloudant

I am currently using cloudant datastore for store data offline.I am facing issue in cloudant query indexing.

{
  "_id": "xxx",
  "_rev": "xxx",
  "check_in_date": "02/01/2017",
  "check_out_date": "08/01/2017",
  "username": "abc"
}

How to query date range between check_in_date and check_out_date.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the [sync-android](https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android) library.

You can't query date range. The query [grammar](https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android/blob/master/doc/query.md#grammar) documentation provides all the operators and types that can be used with them.